# Follow system in CakePHP

Tags: php, cakephp

Basically I want to achieve a follow system like the one in Twitter and others, in CakePHP.

I have a users table which has all the user info. On each user's profile, is a follow button that once clicked, must create a new record in a "follows" table which contains a user_id, i.e., the user's ID and a follower_id i.e. the logged in user's ID. So every time a user clicks follow on a profile, it should create a new record in "follows".

I saw a few questions like this, but didn't find a perfect and a helpful answer.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: What's the problem to do it?  share code here

Comment: I wanted to know what kind of a association must be formed. To form a HABTM, I need two tables. But I have only users table and a User model. I can use only one table for HABTM, but I don't exactly know how to do it in this case. And if not HABTM, can I achieve it through another type of association? Or without any association?

Comment: Right now, in my User model I have a defined a HABTM relation.
public $hasAndBelongsToMany = array(
    'Follower' =>
    array(
        'className' => 'User',
        'joinTable' => 'follows',
        'foreignKey' => 'user_id',
        'associationForeignKey' => 'follower_id',
        'unique' => 'keepExisting',
        'conditions' => '',
        'fields' => '',
        'order' => '',
        'limit' => '',
        'offset' => '',
        'finderQuery' => '',
        'with' => 'Follow'
    )
);

Comment: And using below code to save:
$data['Follower']['id'] = $this->Auth->user('id');
                $data['User']['id'] = $user_id;
                $this->User->Follower->save($data);
                //$this->set('follower', $this->Follower->find('all'));
                $this->set('data', $data);

Comment: You are on the right way. Do you have any errors?

Comment: No errors. But no data is being saved in my follows table. I'm even passing $data back to the view file to view what the data is. And according to general HABTM saving techniques, it is right. But it still isn't saving right. When I use $this->User->Follower->find('all'); I get all the users in the users table, like it is supposed to. But it doesn't save any data in the follows table, which is joined table.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Something like:

**User Model**

```
public $hasAndBelongsToMany = array(
    'Follower' => array(
        'className' => 'User',
        'joinTable' => 'your_join_table',
        'foreignKey' => 'following_id',
        'associationForeignKey' => 'followed_id',
        'unique' => 'keepExisting' // If you do not want records to be deleted
    ),
    'Followed' => array(
        'className' => 'User',
        'joinTable' => 'your_join_table',
        'foreignKey' => 'followed_id',
        'associationForeignKey' => 'following_id',
        'unique' => 'keepExisting' // If you do not want records to be deleted
    )
)
```

assuming your $user_id = 2 is the currently logged user and the $followed_id = 10 is the user he wants to follow then you have to create an array like

```
$data = array(
    'User' => array(
        'id' => 2,

    ),
    'Followed' => array(
        'Followed' => array(
            0 => 10,
            1 => 12  // if you want you can store 2 records at the same time,
                         // i.e. you have a checkbox for every user 
                         //and the follower can check multiple cheboxes before submit           
        )
    )
)
```

and then

```
$this->User->saveAll($data)
```

Comment: How do I save the data through this? And which one of following_id and followed_id is the currently logged in user ID and which one is the ID of the other user's ID?

Comment: I used your method exactly the way you told me to. It still doesn't save any data in the joined table follows.

Comment: @ashishsanjayrao do you get any error? Do you see some INSERT query in your SQL logs?

Comment: No. There is no INSERT query.

Comment: @ashishsanjayrao I tried the same exact code and it inserts an entry in my join table. Be aware that every time it update a user it deletes the old records. I'm going to edit my answer to take into account of this

Comment: I'm using the exact same codes too! But nothing is getting saved in my table. I guess the only difference between our attempts is the table. Could you please discuss how your table is structured? Sorry for all this trouble.

Comment: Also, when I user $this->User->find('all') it doesn't show any other data other than only the various users. Isn't it supposed to show the data associated too?

Comment: @ashishsanjayrao Please edit your answer posting your User model code and your UsersController code because my code should work

Comment: Thanks! Got it working. Was just rechecking everything. Made a few small changes and it just worked. Thanks again!

Answer (score 0):

If you have the workflow, nothing stops you from trying to implement it.

Create your `User` model, a `Follows` model which has a ManyToMany relation to `User`; implement a controller that does the actual follow, between the current user (taken from the `Auth` component) and the user to be followed (taken from the URL, most probably); finally add a view with the follow button that calls the controller method.

Keep trying and if you stumble upon some difficulties, share what you've tried and we'll be able to help you.

Comment: So you're suggesting me to create a new model and controller for the follow system, instead of doing it through the UsersController? And by  ManyToMany you mean HABTM right? The joined table's name is follows. So should I create a controller and model for the joined table itself?

Comment: No, I think I wasn't clear enough. @arilia explained in better in his answer. I wasn't talking about two models, but define two relationships of ManyToMany type (HABTM) from the `User` model. No, you shouldn't create anything for the joined table.

Comment: Sorry I misunderstood. Thanks anyways. I'm trying Arilia's method now. However, it's still not really saving the data yet.